# RSACryptoServiceProvider and hardware failover

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

Lets say we have a PC used to decrypt data using the RSACryptoServiceProvider.

The PC dies and we can no longer decrypt data because the public key used to encrypt data will not be any good on another PC (I think).

Is the only way to ensure successful decryption to export the public and private keys so if the PC goes down we can import the keys onto another PC and then we can decrypt data again.

If that's the case where do you store the private key to ensure privacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are products called Hardware Security Modules (HSMs) designed to provide secure and reliable key storage. Most of them have software to interface with windows Crypto APIs, so that for example your RSACryptoServiceProvider will transparently use the HSM.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is similar to Windows reminding you to [Backup your encryption key](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Back-up-Encrypting-File-System-EFS-certificate)

In that article after exporting your key they suggest:

> Store the backup copy of your EFS certificate in a safe place.

What is a safe place? I'd consider these 2 safe:

1) On an external disk not connected to the network (a thumb drive)
2) A printed copy of the key, ie base64 of the key bytes. (this is going a bit far I reckon)

Comment: ... and preferable both not located near the computer the working key is on (or a fire or such can destroy both at the same time).